# Mac seldom lost wifi connection

Tags: wifi, macintosh, macos

I was using mac (15-inch, 2018) with os 10.15.6 (19G73)

these days, i seldom get wifi connection failure with following log.

```
Mon Jul 27 14:27:13.914 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:13.914  Mon Jul 27 14:27:13.950 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.061 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.061  Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.062 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.062  Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.109 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.109  Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.117 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:15.146 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.384 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.384  Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.385 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.385  Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.434 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.434  Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.443 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:16.472 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.566 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.566  Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.567 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.567  Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.614 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.615  Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.624 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:17.653 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.740 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.740  <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.741  Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.789 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.789  Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.798 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:18.827 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.675 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.676  <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.676  Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.722 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.722  Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.732 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:20.761 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.753 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.753  Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.754 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.754  Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.802 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.802  Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.813 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:21.843 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.786 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.786  Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.787 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.787  Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.836 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.836  Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.845 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:23.873 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.092 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.093  Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.093 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.094  Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.143 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.144  Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.153 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:26.181 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.133 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.134  <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.134  Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.187 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.187  Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.196 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:36.224 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.111 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.111  Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.111 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.111  Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.159 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.159  Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.168 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:46.197 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.283 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.283  Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.284 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.284  Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.333 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.333  Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.341 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:27:56.368 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.828 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.828  <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.828  Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.894 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.894  Mon Jul 27 14:28:05.929 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.809 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.810  
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.810 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.810  Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.864 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.864 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.973 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.974 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.979 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.980 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.982 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:15.984 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.179 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.179  Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.207 <kernel> AppleBCMWLANCore::getSSIDData(): Get failure: APPLE80211_IOC_SSID: -528342013
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.883 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.883  Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.883 <kernel> postMessage::1349 APPLE80211_M_BSSID_CHANGED received
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.883  Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.949 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:25.949 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.043 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.043 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.046 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.046 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.048 <airportd[247]> ERROR: rapportd (365) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:26.049 <airportd[247]> ERROR: sharingd (415) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jul 27 14:28:47.683 Apple80211Set:9543 Processing APPLE80211_IOC_ROAM
Mon Jul 27 14:28:47.683 Apple80211Set:9557 Processing APPLE80211_IOC_ROAM dataRef:0x7fca1e93e280
Mon Jul 27 14:28:47.683 
Apple80211Set:9578 CFType is CFData
```

any one know the reason of the symptom and how to solve it, thank in advance.

Comment: `seldom` means `very infrequently`

Comment: it seems have no rules and unpredictable